# Polyfill for FileReader API

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer-9, filereader

Please help me out on using fileReader polyfill for IE9. Im unable to get it out on how to use it.

Please correct me if im doing anything wrong here. Im trying to use the FileReader API Shim for IE9. But on change event of the input type = file, Im still getting files attribute not defined on event error message
Posting the code below for your reference`

```html
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div id="fileReaderSWFObject"></div>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" /><br />
    <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="some text...">
</div>

<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.FileReader.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
// Variables


// Init
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 9) {
    
    $('#imageLoader').fileReader({
        id: 'fileReaderSWFObject',
        filereader: 'filereader.swf',
        expressInstall: 'expressInstall.swf',
        debugMode: true,
        callback: function () { console.log('filereader ready'); }
    });
}
$('#imageLoader').change(function (e) {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 9) {
        console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
    } 
});
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to comeup with the solution for IE9 polyfill FileReader API by https://github.com/Aymkdn/FileToDataURI

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    <object id="file-object">
    </object>
    <div id="file-result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Flash = {
      /* Flash.getFileData() is called after the file has been read */
      getFileData: function(base64) {
        showResult(base64)
      },
      /* getButtonLabel() permits to define another label for the "Load a file" button in the Flash version */
      getButtonLabel: function() {
        return "Load a file";
      }
    };

    // we just want to show the result into the div
    function showResult(b) {
      $('#file-result').text(b)
    }

    // check if the FileReader API exists... if not then load the Flash object
    if (typeof FileReader !== "function")
      // we use 80px by 23px, because we want the object to have the same size than the button
      swfobject.embedSWF("FileToDataURI.swf", "file-object", "80px", "23px", "10", "expressInstall.swf", {}, {}, {});
    else {
      // replace the <object> by an input file
      $('#file-object').replaceWith('<input type="file" id="file-object" value="Load a file" />');
      $('#file-object').on('change', function(e) {
        var files = e.target.files,file;

        if (!files || files.length == 0) return;
        file = files[0];

        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
          // ATTENTION: to have the same result than the Flash object we need to split
          // our result to keep only the Base64 part
          showResult(e.target.result.split(",")[1]);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
    }
    </script>
```